# C++ Type erasure with traits

Tags: c++, c++17, type-erasure, stdany

I wanted to know that this is possible to make an erased type that conforms to a trait like this one :

```
template<class T>
using read_t = std::conditional_t<true,
    decltype(std::declval<T>().Read(uint16_t{})),
    std::integral_constant<uint8_t (T::*)(uint16_t), &T::Read>>;
```

and use it like this ?

```
using any_readable_t = any<read_t>; 
auto test(any_readable_t &r) -> uint8_t {
     return r.Read(0);
}
```

Comment: Is it `.read` or `.Read`?

Comment: this is .Read, I derped.

Comment: Take a look at Boost.TypeErasure http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html

Comment: Don't you want *concept* ?

Comment: @Jarod42 How could I use concept with llvm 5 ?

Comment: What is this templated `any`?

Comment: @papagaga It's a template type that accepts every other types that conforms to a trait, it's just a placeholder to see if such type exists.

Answer (score 1):

Without any external library, there's a lot of work that needs to be done to achieve what you want. Using Louis Dionne's [`dyno`](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno):

```
DYNO_INTERFACE(Readable,
    (read, uint8_t (uint16_t))
);

auto test(Readable& r) -> uint8_t {
    return r.read(0);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know this library but I can't make it work with CMake due to HanaConfig.cmake missing :/

Comment: @uknys: open an issue on GitHub? https://github.com/ldionne/dyno/issues